# SUM count of one field with count of JOINED rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following three tables (`observations`, `aspect_labels`, `aspects`):

### Observations Table

#### Structure

[image: Observations table]

#### Data

[image: Observations data]

### Aspects Labels Table

#### Structure

[image: aspect_labels table]

#### Data

[image: aspect_labels data]

### Aspects Table

#### Structure

[image: aspects table]

#### Data

[image: aspects data]

The idea behind these three tables is that each `observation` has a single `Main_Development` and `Main_Positive` but also has an infinite number of additional `Positive` aspects and `Development` aspects.

So, for example, if I input an observation now (into the `observations` table) the `Main_Positive` might be `Student Enthusiasm` (`aspect_label` ID 1) and the `Main_Development` might be `Student Engagement` (`aspect_label` ID 2). However I may also add in a standard `Positive` aspect of `Expectations` (`aspect_label` ID 3) which goes into the `aspects` table.

What I'm trying to do, grouped by `Teacher_ID`, is display the number of times each member of staff has had each `aspect` listed in their observations.

So, I want to see that `D Wraight` has had 2 `Student Engagement`, 0 `Expectations`, 1 `Student Enthusiasm` etc.

This query does exactly that for the `Main_Positive` aspect from the `observations` table but I have no idea how to add the rows from the `aspects` table into the query.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(sta.Firstname, " ", sta.Surname) AS `Member of Staff`,
    SUM(IF(o.`Main_Positive` = 1, 1, 0)) AS `Student enthusiasm`,
    SUM(IF(o.`Main_Positive` = 2, 1, 0)) AS `Student engagement`,
    SUM(IF(o.`Main_Positive` = 3, 1, 0)) AS `Expectations`,
    SUM(IF(o.`Main_Positive` = 4, 1, 0)) AS `Safe and supportive environment`,
    SUM(IF(o.`Main_Positive` = 5, 1, 0)) AS `Attitude and values of teacher`,
    SUM(IF(o.`Main_Positive` = 6, 1, 0)) AS `Objectives to stretch all students`,
  << MORE GOES HERE >>
FROM frog_observations.observations o
LEFT JOIN frog_shared.staff sta ON o.Teacher_ID = sta.ID
GROUP BY o.Teacher_ID
ORDER BY sta.Surname ASC, sta.Firstname ASC
```

The query produces this output (when exported to CSV by PHPMA):

[image: Output]

How do I amend the query to include joined rows from the `aspects` table?

**EDIT**: SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75cf3/1/0

Comment: Some DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle would be nice, TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. If the data is sensitive then obviously substitute it with junk data somehow.

Comment: @Strawberry done - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be319/2/0. I don't know how to add in the desired result set though, as it's essentially the same as the query I've written... just with bigger numbers :)

Comment: @Strawberry updated again with better data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75cf3/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this as it stands as it would result in a variable number of columns (unless you want to change the SQL every time another aspect is added).

You can do something like this:-

```
SELECT CONCAT(s.Firstname, ' ', Surname), al.Title, IFNULL(SUM(AspectCnt), 0)
FROM staff s
CROSS JOIN aspect_labels al
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.Teacher_ID, o.Main_Positive AS AspectId, COUNT(*) AS AspectCnt
    FROM observations o
    GROUP BY o.Teacher_ID, o.Main_Positive
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.Teacher_ID, o.Main_Development AS AspectId, COUNT(*) AS AspectCnt
    FROM observations o
    GROUP BY o.Teacher_ID, o.Main_Development
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.Teacher_ID, a.Aspect_ID AS AspectId, COUNT(*) AS AspectCnt
    FROM observations o
    INNER JOIN aspects a
    ON o.ID = a.Observation_ID
    GROUP BY o.Teacher_ID, a.Aspect_ID
) Sub1
ON s.ID = Sub1.Teacher_ID
AND al.ID = Sub1.AspectId
GROUP BY CONCAT(s.Firstname, ' ', Surname), al.Title
ORDER BY CONCAT(s.Firstname, ' ', Surname), al.Title
```

Which gives you one line per member of staff per aspect and then loop around in code to sort out your columns.

EDIT - With fixed columns:-

```
SELECT CONCAT(s.Firstname, ' ', Surname), 
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(Sub1.AspectId = 1, 1, 0)), 0) AS `Student enthusiasm`,
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(Sub1.AspectId = 2, 1, 0)), 0) AS `Student engagement`,
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(Sub1.AspectId = 3, 1, 0)), 0) AS `Expectations`,
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(Sub1.AspectId = 4, 1, 0)), 0) AS `Safe and supportive environment`,
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(Sub1.AspectId = 5, 1, 0)), 0) AS `Attitude and values of teacher`,
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(Sub1.AspectId = 6, 1, 0)), 0) AS `Objectives to stretch all students`
FROM staff s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.Teacher_ID, o.Main_Positive AS AspectId
    FROM observations o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.Teacher_ID, o.Main_Development AS AspectId
    FROM observations o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.Teacher_ID, a.Aspect_ID AS AspectId
    FROM observations o
    INNER JOIN aspects a
    ON o.ID = a.Observation_ID
) Sub1
ON s.ID = Sub1.Teacher_ID
GROUP BY CONCAT(s.Firstname, ' ', Surname)
ORDER BY CONCAT(s.Firstname, ' ', Surname)
```

It might be quicker to split it up a bit to get all the counts using the teacher id to group on, then join the results back to the teachers table to get the name. Would avoid grouping on the concatenated field.

Comment: For the purposes of the question - and sorry, I should've made this clear - I'm actually Ok with having a fixed number of aspects. They're our school's teacher standards and won't be changing any time soon, plus I only need to run this data once a year. Would you be able to give me an example of how you would've done the static variant? Thanks.

Comment: Edited the response to have fixed columns.

Comment: Bingo - thanks for your time, Kickstart, much appreciated. Certainly couldn't have done that one on my own.